# Meta analysis: can multiple test corrections (i.e. Bonferroni) be applied on the pooled effect p-value?

Tags: meta-analysis, bonferroni, meta-regression

I plan to do a meta-analysis including the effect size of each cohort as the objectives. I'd like to ask if I could apply multiple test corrections (i.e. Bonferroni) on the pooled effect p-value.

I couldn't find a similar paper or other reference. I'd be very grateful if you could give me any suggestions.

Comment: There are a number of methods for combining p-values which can be useful if you do not have effect sizes but if you do then why not meta-analyses the effect sizes?

Answer (score 0):

P-values for summary effect sizes are not useful. Typically, we consider the summary effect of a meta-analysis "exploratory", and do not perform adjustments for multiple tests. If you have been concerned with type-I error rates ("false positives"), you can:

- select the most homogeneous set of studies possible,
- use 99% confidence intervals.
- employ a random-effects model
- describe the variability via 95% predictive intervals.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. In this meta, I regard each cohort as each 'study' and I wanna know if the pooled effect is significant across the cohorts.